# Laravel api routes not working, it's always redirecting

Tags: laravel, api, controller, routes

I am having an issue with laravel doing my backend Api.
What I am trying to do is return logged user data with Auth::user();
I wrote the controller, the route for the controller method in api.php but when I try to go to the /api/route I am redirected to Home.

I also tried to remove the  __construct() method from the controller, When I do this and try to go to the /api/route, dd($user) is returning null.

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Resources\TeacherResource;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class teacherApiController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function information(){
        $user = Auth::user();
        dd($user);
    }
}
```

Api.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('information', 'API\teacherApiController@information');
```

Anything I am doing wrong?
I am using the laravel authentication for register and login users.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are not authenticated before calling this route that's why when the **__construct** was there it redirected you to the home, that's also why `Auth::user()` returns you null.
You are probably not authenticated before calling this route.

To manage the authentication you used laravel passport or even used JWT

Comment: Before I tried to go api/information I login an account. Whats is that of passaport and JWT? how It works and what is used for?

Comment: APIs typically use tokens to authenticate users and do not maintain session state between requests.
So you will have to go through these layers to be able to authenticate you, they will provide you with a token to identify each of your users.

Comment: Nice vidéo for JWT authentification : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eX9Pj-GhZs

Comment: Humnn, so this is why the redirect happens. Beeing login is not suficient to auth in the api, I need to provide some kind of authentication with tokens (passaport and JWT). I will search and see the video! Thank you!

Comment: I followed this video and the next one correctly, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRbuInSwU9U&list=PLB4AdipoHpxaHDLIaMdtro1eXnQtl_UvE&index=27 , and the page api route stills redirect me. I do not want to use tokens and authentication, just like this video, because I am afraid of saving people token in localStorage or something else